# Not able to disable Instant Run feature in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-instant-run, instant-run

Android Studio Version: 3.1.2

I am not able to disable the instant run checkbox in the android studio.

Tried to disable from the below path

File → Settings → Build, Execution, Deployment → Instant Run and uncheck Enable Instant Run( the checkbox is grey out and I'm unable to click on it).

I tried uninstalling the android studio also. Please help me out here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's tied to the app's gradle. https://developer.android.com/studio/run/#instant-run

I'm assuming you already used it once for the app. Try uninstalling the app from the target device/emulator (and unplugging/stopping it) then go to File-> Invalidate Caches and Restart. Then see if it still doesn't let you.

EDIT: Make sure gradle files are updated and the versions match.

Comment: Already tried this. when i try to sync i'm getting this error "Gradle sync failed: Failed to notify project evaluation listener." For correcting above error I need to disable instant run. Please help me.

Comment: Can you post your log report that shows what part of the sync failed?

Comment: Thanks for helping. There is an issue with my gradle files. I have changed the version and did sync, it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Disable automatic activity restart

Open the Settings or Preferences dialog: On Windows or Linux, select File > Settings from the menu bar. On Mac OSX, select Android Studio > Preferences from the menu bar.

Navigate to Build, Execution, Deployment > Instant Run.

Uncheck the box next to Restart activity on code changes.